# discord.py - "member" argument always returns a string even when using the converter discord.User

Tags: python, discord.py

As said in the title, I have a mute function in a Moderation cog which takes in a member argument, however even when using the converter, "member" ends up being a string looking like this "user#0000". Every other methods of Moderation class take member as an object. What could be causing this ?

Here is mute():

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="unspecified"):
    """"""
    try:
        await member.add_roles(self.get_role(ctx.guild.id, "muted_role"))
        await member.remove_roles(self.get_role(ctx.guild.id, "default_role"))

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"**Error**: `{e}`")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.id} was muted.")

        if not self.get_channel(ctx.guild.id, "log_channel"):
            await ctx.send(self.no_log_chan)
            return

        await self.get_channel(ctx.guild.id, "log_channel").send(
            self.get_embed(
                "__MUTE__",
                ctx.message.author,
                "#00FF00",
                f"{member.id} was muted by {ctx.message.author} \nReason : *{reason}*",
                datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                ctx.message.author.avatar_url,
            )
        )
```

and here's my kick() method which works perfectly fine:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.User, *, reason="unspecified"):
    """"""
    try:
        await ctx.guild.kick(member)

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"**Error**: `{e}`")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.id} was kicked.")

        if not self.get_channel(ctx.guild.id, "log_channel"):
            await ctx.send(self.no_log_chan)
            return

        await self.get_channel(ctx.guild.id, "log_channel").send(
            self.get_embed(
                "__KICK__",
                ctx.message.author,
                "#00FF00",
                f"{member.id} was kicked from the server by {ctx.message.author} \nReason : *{reason}*",
                datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                member.avatar_url,
            )
        )
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain more what you mean by it becomes a string? Like do you get an error? If so what is it? Also, just in general, you cannot add roles to a discord.User object, only a discord.Member obj, User's are not specific to a guild.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for being so vague, I get an error saying `"str" object has no attribute "id"`, and printing member gets me "Mass#1111" for example.  And I still get this issue when using discord.Member

Comment: Just a pro tip: `print` converts what you give it, to str. A User/Member obj cast to an str yields `name#1234` format. If you try doing `print(type(member))` Does this give you str?

Comment: thanks I didn't know that, the type of member is actually <class 'discord.member.Member'> but now the function doesn't do anything and no output in the console :/

Comment: your using `add_roles()` and `remove_roles()` with a `User` type. A `User` type doesn't have those methods. I think you mean to use `discord.Member`

Comment: I've tried with discord.Member but I still get the `'str' object has no attribute 'id'`, this also means the method somehow passed the add_roles/remove_roles part but on discord the user I mention is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Until the last version, it worked like this:

```
async def Function(ctx, member:discord.User):
```

Hope it was usefull.